# how to create package in a way that using `import mypackage` will import the files i need

Tags: python, pip, packaging

i am trying to create a pip package.
my file structure is:

```
setup.py
README.md
LICENSE
mypackage/
    mypackage.py
    __init__.py
```

my `__init__.py` looks like this:

```py
from mypackage import *
```

mypackage.py

```py
def somefunc():
    return "some value"
```

any my setup.py looks like this:

```py
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
setuptools.setup(
     name='mypackage',  
     version='0.0.1',
     author="Yonatan Medan",
     description="some description",
     long_description=long_description,
   long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
     packages=["mypackage"],
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
         "Operating System :: OS Independent",
     ],

 )
```

i packaged the package with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`,
and installed it with `pip install dist/mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl`
the problem is that when i try to import it with python

i need to do something like this to import `somefunc`:

```py
from mypackage.mypackage import somefunc
```

what i want is:

```py
from mypackage import somefunc
```

how could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the following directory structure, you can do this 2 ways.

```
package
├── hello.py
├── __init__.py
```

Either define the function inside the `__init__.py` like below

```
from . import hello

def somefunc():
    print("Some function inside __init__.py")
```

Then at repl you can do

```
>>> from package import somefunc
>>> somefunc
<function somefunc at 0x7f98e380d400>
>>> somefunc()
Some function inside __init__.py
>>>
```

Or you need to import `*` from the module inside your `__init__.py`, like below.

```
from .hello import *


def somefunc():
    print("Some function inside __init__.py")
```

And then import like this

```
>>> import package
>>> package.greet()
Hello
>>> from package import *
>>> greet()
Hello
```

Also as a side it is better to keep the package name and the module name different for sake of clarity.

Comment: Thx for the reply, I would like to avoid placing the code I want to import inside `__init__.py`. isn't there a way to work around writing the function directly Inside `__init__.py` by importing it in some way? It must be possible because for example if you write `import pandas` you can directly excess `pandas.DataFrame` and I don't see any `DataFrame` code inside pandas main `__init__.py`

Comment: Ok it worked! the problem was that i was writing `from mypackage import *
` instead of `from .mypackage import *` and because my package and module were both named mypackage it didn't make any error. while i thought i imported the module imported the package.